# JQuery select id to match a non-English characters

Tags: jquery

I have this id 'ŠKODY' and when I try to select it I get the following error: **JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #ŠKODY**

This is my simple code and thank you.

```
alert("" +  $("#ŠKODY").length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is technically possible to use non-English identificators, I would strongly recommend stop using them. Give English names to your elements and classes to avoid any problems with different encodings / locales / browsers etc. Using non-English names in your code does not provide any advantages, but makes your code unmaintainable and non-understandable by international developers.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I wish I could do that, but the users are not English speakers.  How can I convert non English character to English characters?

Comment: @Ado Your users do not see the names of your elements :) If you open any non-English web-site (for example, http://poland.pl/ or http://mail.ru), you will see that JavaScript, HTML and CSS are all in English. It is sort of international best practices of web and software development. It applies only to code, not to visible text. For example, you can create an element like `<p id="skody">ŠKODY</p>`.

Comment: My id come from data that the user uses. There is a way to convert them?

Answer (score 0):

All characters are not allowed in HTML identifiers.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

from [HTML specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name).